# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

While creating an alertdialog from within the Adapter class, "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?" I'm getting the error. I tried solutions to errors similar to this, but I was not successful.

**Here's my ChatsAdapter.kt:**
`

```
class ChatsAdapter(
    private var mContext: Context,
    private var mChatList: List<Chat>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatsAdapter.ViewHolder?>() {

private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var message: TextView? = null
    var seen: TextView? = null
    var imageMessageRight: ImageView? = null
    var imageMessageLeft: ImageView? = null

    init {
        message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageItem_message_textView)
        seen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageItem_seen_textView)
        imageMessageRight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageItemRight_imageView)
        imageMessageLeft = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageItemLeft_imageView)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return if (viewType == 1) {
        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.message_item_right_layout, parent, false)
        ViewHolder(view)
    } else {
        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.message_item_left_layout, parent, false)
        ViewHolder(view)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mChatList.size
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val chat: Chat = mChatList[position]

    holder.message!!.text = chat.message

        if (firebaseUser.uid == chat.sender) {
            holder.message!!.setOnClickListener {
                AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.CustomAlertDialog)
                    .setTitle("What do you want?")
                    .setMessage("")
                    .setPositiveButton("Delete Message") { dialog, _ ->
                        deleteMessage(position, holder)
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }
                .create()
                .show()
            }
        }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (mChatList[position].sender.equals(firebaseUser.uid)) {
        1
    } else {
        0
    }
}

private fun deleteMessage(position: Int, holder: ChatsAdapter.ViewHolder) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Chats")
        .child(mChatList[position].messageId!!)
        .removeValue()
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "Message Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    holder.itemView.context,
                    "Failed, Message Not Deleted!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
}
}`
```

**And here's my error:**

`setOnBackInvokedCallback(): No window state for  package:com.mahmutalperenunal.chatapp setOnBackInvokedCallback(): No window state for package:com.mahmutalperenunal.chatapp FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.mahmutalperenunal.chatapp, PID: 4463                                                                                                 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running? at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1312) at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:405) at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148) at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:352) at com.mahmutalperenunal.chatapp.adapter.ChatsAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda$6(ChatsAdapter.kt:144) at com.mahmutalperenunal.chatapp.adapter.ChatsAdapter.$r8$lambda$ZXeWNt_zWtawSAvN8VWNABoKa5Q(Unknown Source:0) at com.mahmutalperenunal.chatapp.adapter.ChatsAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda7.onClick(Unknown Source:6) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506) at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483) at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)`

How can I solve this problem?